# Rails template rendering slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm currently using *mongrel* server running rails2.3.5 with ruby1.8, and got this odd behavior:

```
Rendered common/_header (3.1ms)
Rendered common/_categories (1.2ms)
Rendered common/_footer (1.2ms)
Completed in 6934ms (View: 5897, DB: 174)   ## 5897ms... to rendering a local page??
```

why?

### updated

only one user there.. i'm working on my notebook, the problem lies in the rendering of view, i thought.  but i just can't figure out why, since there's nothing fancy in the partials layouts, and templates.

### the server log

```
Processing PostController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-12-29 22:09:35) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"post"}
  Post Columns (4.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `posts`
  Post Load (3.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE (`posts`.`id` = 1) 
  User Columns (4.5ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
  User Load (3.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`persistence_token` = 'XXXXXXXXXX') LIMIT 1
  Answer Columns (3.5ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `answers`
  Reading Columns (2.5ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `readings`
  Reading Load (1.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `readings` WHERE (`readings`.`user_id` = 9) AND (`readings`.post_id = 1) LIMIT 1
Rendering template within layouts/base
Rendering post/show
  Vote Load (1.5ms)   SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE (`votes`.post_id = 1) 
  Vote Columns (3.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `votes`
  SQL (1.0ms)   SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `readings` WHERE (`readings`.post_id = 1) 
  User Load (3.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  posts_tags Columns (3.3ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `posts_tags`
  Tag Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `posts_tags` ON `tags`.id = `posts_tags`.tag_id WHERE (`posts_tags`.post_id = 1 ) 
  Tag Columns (5.4ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `tags`
  SQL (1.1ms)   SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `answers` WHERE (`answers`.post_id = 1) 
  Answer Load (23.4ms)   SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE (`answers`.post_id = 1) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  Digg Load (2.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 9) 
  Digg Columns (3.3ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `diggs`
  Reply Load (2.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 9) 
  Reply Columns (3.4ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `replies`
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  Digg Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 10) 
  Reply Load (2.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 10) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  User Load (3.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  Digg Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 11) 
  Reply Load (2.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 11) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.9ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 12) 
  Reply Load (1.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 12) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (2.5ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 13) 
  Reply Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 13) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (11.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 14) 
  Reply Load (1.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 14) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 15) 
  Reply Load (1.9ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 15) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 16) 
  Reply Load (11.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 16) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 17) 
  Reply Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 17) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (10.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 18) 
  Reply Load (2.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 18) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 19) 
  Reply Load (2.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 19) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (8.6ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 20) 
  Reply Load (1.6ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 20) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 21) 
  Reply Load (1.6ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 21) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 22) 
  Reply Load (1.6ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 22) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.7ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 23) 
  Reply Load (7.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 23) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 24) 
  Reply Load (8.6ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 24) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 25) 
  Reply Load (2.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 25) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 9) 
  Digg Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 26) 
  Reply Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 26) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 4) 
  Digg Load (1.6ms)   SELECT * FROM `diggs` WHERE (`diggs`.answer_id = 27) 
  Reply Load (1.8ms)   SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE (`replies`.answer_id = 27) 
Rendered common/_header (3.2ms)
Rendered common/_categories (1.5ms)
Rendered common/_footer (10.8ms)
Completed in 7407ms (View: 6376, DB: 194) | 200 OK [http://localhost/posts/1]
```

#### updated

seems like there is no indexing in my join tables.

Comment: Impossible to say without more information. What are you doing in those partials?

Comment: Rendered common/_header (3.2ms) 

Rendered common/_categories (1.5ms) 

Rendered common/_footer (10.8ms) 

Completed in 7407ms (View: 6376, DB: 194) | 200 OK [http://localhost/posts/1]


It's pretty clear here that its your view, and not the db access. you can see from the timing it's not header, footer or categories partials. Can you post your main view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various things that can result in this:

- Your server is slow. Consider using mod_rails. If you're already doing this, you might need some more RAM or another kind of hardware upgrade?
- You have too many requests to the database. Look at the log to see what's going on
- You're not using caching in an effective manner. Depending on your server there are various solutions
- Your code is not optimized. Try running benchmarks to see what you could improve.

Comment: I don't see how having too many images or JavaScript files would impact these values. Loading them is not part of the render - it's something the browser does afterwards. The other points are great.

Comment: this is fairly hard to pinpoint your issue with no more information, but these are guidelines regarding things to check. I think the profiler of firebug will help you a lot with your problem

Comment: @samir, that's true that javascript are not part of it (edited my answer). Images... are you sure? This I'm not sure

Comment: Samir is correct. Rails is reporting how long the server-side view rendering took to perform. Firebug is a tool for debugging client-side code. It won't help in this case.

Comment: @john and samir: ok, noted, thanks for the input. I edited my answer based on what you said

Answer (score 0):

My steps here: profile, fix issues found via that way... and if that still doesn't work, look into caching in Rails.

But only cache after profiling

Answer (score 0):

Let's see more of the log, start with the "Processing ..." for the controller all the way through to the "Completed..."